# What is the difference between html pageshow and load events?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onload, pageshow

HTML5 has a [pageshow event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/pageshow). In what instances does it work differently than the body's `onload` handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pageshow event fires every time the page is loaded whereas the load event doesn’t fire in Firefox 1.5 when the page is loaded from cache.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, there is a far more important difference between the two.

According to my test on iOS, if you load a local page from a `WkWebView`, hit a link to jump to another page and use the `goBack` function to go back the previous page, only `onpageshow` will fire, `onload` will not.

Comment: The page is loaded from cache when you go back, so you are not describing any difference.